# Как положить содержимое php-файла в html файл

Tags: php, html, jquery

Как можно класть данные из php-файла в html.
Вот пример html файла

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Пример php файла

```
<?
include('db.php');   //Подключение к бд
$Sql= "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column1` = 1

$Sql= $PDOdb->prepare($Sql);
$Sql->execute(); //Запрос

while ($data= $Sql->fetch()) {
print('<div>');
print($data['column2']);

....

print('</div>');
}

?>
```

Comment: Так не получится. Обычно происходит наоборот. HTML кладут в PHP-файл. Скажите почему вам нужно именно так, возможно, есть какое-то другое решение.

Comment: Сделать аякс запрос к php файлу, взять данные, положить данные в нужные блоки используя jquery

Comment: Мне это нужно для загрузки html - файла на сторонний сервис, php файлы туда не грузятся. а что бы для каждой строки не писать отдельный html файл хочу сделать обработчик который будет оращатся к php файлу и брать данные оттуда

Comment: Тогда просто используйте AJAX, например.

Comment: А можно через `<iframe>`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php ?